# Loop over lines in file, create list from 2nd column

Tags: python, list, file, for-loop, output

I'm trying to loop over the lines in an output file I created that looks like this:

```
2020-03-19, 22.0
2020-03-20, 6.0
2020-03-21, 5.0
```

And then create and print a list with the numbers in the 2nd column.

This is just my main and the function I'm having trouble with:

````
def main(): 
    for file in FILE_PATH_INPUT:
        fWriteOutputFile(file)
    print(fReadOutputFile(FILE_PATH_OUTPUT))
```


def fReadInputFile(pFile):
    casesList = []
    with open(pFile, 'r') as fi:
        lines = fi.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.rstrip().split(',')
            casesList.append(str(line[1]))
    return casesList
        

```


**What I'm expecting:
[66, 6, 5]
what I'm getting:
casesList.append(str(line[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range**
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this section of code:

```
        line = line.rstrip().split(',')
        caseslist = str(line[1]) + ','
        casesList.append(caseslist)
```

In the second line, 'line' still contain text (it's a string) , You have to convert to integer.
Correct way is:

```
        line = line.rstrip().split(',')
        casesList.append( int( line[1])
```

Also, the "file.close()" is located after the 'return'. So the 'close' will never be executed.

Comment: thank you, however I'm getting an index error with that. it says list index out of range

Comment: It may happen if split() return only one (or 0) element. That will happen if a comma is missing or if you have a blank line in your datafile. You can test if len(line) <2 and  if that's True, skip the line where int() and append() are.

Comment: You may also up-score my comment.

Comment: i'm not allowed to yet because I'm a new user but when I unlock the feature I'll make sure to do that

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the list, you don't need manually add "," to each element. Instead, you can write fReadOutputFile in the following way:

```
def fReadOutputFile(pFile):
    casesList = []
    with open(pFile, 'r') as fi:
        lines = fi.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.rstrip().split(',')
            casesList.append(str(line[1]))
    return casesList
```

Comment: Do you know why I get an IndexError when I try that?

Comment: I've also tried:file = open(pFile, 'r')
 casesList = []
 for line in file:
  line = line.split()
  for item in line:
   caseslist = line[1] 
   casesList.append(caseslist)
 return casesList
 file.close()                                                                                      but it doubles each number

Comment: I think index error is because this line: casesList.append(str(line[1])), make sure line[1] always exist, print it out to make sure you parse it correctly.

Comment: the file has many lines like this : 2022-11-02, 0.0.    I'm trying to refer to the 0 with index[1], so I'm sure it always exists but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Then you need to provide your code lines and the error message, then we can help you debug this error.

Comment: casesList.append(str(line[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: then its “line[1] error